# how to create scripting languages

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, data-mining, scripting-language

I'd really like to know what knowledge do I have to pursue in order to create scripting languages from the ground up, probably using C++, maybe python, for those are the languages I know.

I've searched through SO similar questions, but nothing comes close of what I'm asking. I intend to understand language processing, not natural language, but scripts that doesn't have the focus on human readability, only on functionality.

My first idea, without any technical background, was to create a scripting language that assimilates a bunch of logical statements and making use of advanced built-in algorithms like logical reasoning, pattern recognition, neural networks an statistical analysis, in order to provide lots of useful(or not) information.

Sorry my bad english, I learned online, as almost everything I cited here :D and that kinda explains my lack of theorical background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend you read the source code for Lua. It's very small (~12k lines of code) and written in very clean C, which you should be able to get if you get C++.

Comment: Is there any good reason, aside maybe from the learning process, to actually create your new own language that is 100% certain going to be worse than all other established scripting languages out there?

Comment: High-level questions like this are now considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions are expected to be about specific programming issues, while this is a too-broad questions about language design. It is closer to being on-topic for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), but I don't know their policies very well.

Comment: I suspect someone down-voted your question simply because you didn't phrase the title as a meaningful question. Consider revising?

Comment: How is my question off-topic, or not-a-real-question, it is about programming, and it surely is a question, i didn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"From the ground up" is a quite relative term, especially if you consider Python as the implementation language. I think what you are looking for is the implementation of a domain specific language (DSL). Good starting points might be this [book](http://www.amazon.de/Language-Implementation-Patterns-Implementing-Domain-Specific/dp/193435645X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1313993531&sr=8-1) or [this one](http://www.amazon.de/Domain-Specific-Languages-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321712943/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1313993637&sr=1-1). DSLs are a wide topic, so if you provide more details, we might be able to give better tips.

Comment: My English is bad i know, but thanks, i'll check those books out, i'm reading about DSL's and i think this may be exactly the technical term I needed to search around and learn.